# AppCompatDelegate: Failed with appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I did a build on an android with Android Studio, everything was fine, but at some point everything broke down - and an error began to take off on absolutely all devices - I try 3 devices. Application crash on start! I did not change the build.grandle and also did not touch the code associated with it.

Perhaps this is due to the update of some libraries on the server or something?

```
    AppCompatDelegate: Failed to instantiate custom view inflater         android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater. Falling back to default.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater
```

Invalidate caches and restart in Android Studio
Clean and rebuild project
Remove .grandle path and app/build path and restart android studio

```
    AppCompatDelegate: Failed to instantiate custom view inflater         android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater. Falling back to default.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class         "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater" on path:         DexPathList[[zip file         "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file         "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file         "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-        gDUN2dwT1uff5iEdzncEiQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=        [/data/app/com.google.android.gms-gDUN2dwT1uff5iEdzncEiQ==/lib/arm64,         /data/app/com.google.android.gms-        gDUN2dwT1uff5iEdzncEiQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64,         /system/vendor/lib64]]
```

:[Full logcat error](https://pastebin.com/dBg9MVJy) 
 I want do working build without crash